# Can anyone tell me how to install broadcom-wl-5.10.91.9.3-1.fc12.noarch.rpm?

Tags: software-installation, wifi, rpm

```
[root@localhost opt]# rpm -ivh wl-kmod-5.10.91.9.3-3.fc12.6.src.rpm 
warning: wl-kmod-5.10.91.9.3-3.fc12.6.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID a3a882c1
   1:wl-kmod                ########################################### [100%]
[root@localhost opt]# rpm -ivh broadcom-wl-5.10.91.9.3-1.fc12.noarch.rpm 
warning: broadcom-wl-5.10.91.9.3-1.fc12.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID a3a882c1
error: Failed dependencies:
    wl-kmod >= 5.10.91.9.3 is needed by broadcom-wl-5.10.91.9.3-1.fc12.noarch
```

Comment: You installed a _source_ rpm for the dependency. Install the normal one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Find `wl-kmod-5.10.91.9.3-3.fc12.6.rpm` instead of `wl-kmod-5.10.91.9.3-3.fc12.6.src.rpm` -- it shouldn't end in `.src.rpm`